# issue in fetching metadata from static bigquery metadata table

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I need to create BQ table dynamically everyday using Metadadata that is stored in a Static Metadata table.

I can query the table and get the Metadata info to create the table dynamically, where data in Metadata table has the following format:

```
amm_reporting_row:STRING,amm_section:STRING
```

I need to fetch this data as it is. But my query is giving result as :

```
(u'amm_reporting_row:string,amm_section:string',)
```

How can I just get the data and pass it to other function?

```
QUERY = ('SELECT SCHEMA FROM `-----` where File_Subtype = SOME CONDITION ')
query = client.run_sync_query('%s LIMIT 100' % QUERY)
query.use_legacy_sql = False
query.run()
Schema_Defination = query.fetch_data()

  for row in query.rows:
      STRING1 = row
```

And how can I just get the field from table without the  `'(u,'`

Comment: Don't quite understand your question. Are you having some trouble processing `STRING1`? Also, you shouldn't have to worry about the `'u'` as it just an identification that the string is decoded using UTF-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Row is a 1-tuple. You can unpack it using a comma.

```
for row in query.rows:
    string1, = row
    print(string1)
    print(string1.encode('utf8'))
```

Please follow [PEP8's](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) naming advice, and use lower for variables. Use python3 and you'll encounter fewer rough edges on encode / decode issues than with python2.

Comment: Hi @Shikha, welcome to Stackoverflow :)! If J H's answer helped  you, please consider marking it as accepted and/or also upvoting it: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: was not aware of this,however i was searching where to appreciate the person who answered :) .Done now. Many thanks to J H.